# SQLite to ListView(androidhive's version)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, populate

I am trying to insert data from SQLite to a listview. I have tried look for example codes but they do not work. The database part is from AndroidHive's SQL tutorial. In his post the code to get all data in DB is(i edited the data fields) :

```
// Getting All carts item
public List<Cart> getAllCart() {
    List<Cart> cartList = new ArrayList<Cart>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Cart cart = new Cart();
            cart.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            cart.setPID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            cart.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            cart.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3)));
            cart.setQut(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
            // Adding cart to list
            cartList.add(cart);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return cart list
    return cartList;
}
```

how do put this "getAllCart()" to my listview. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get data from SQLite you can try like this:

```
      public List<String[]> selectAll()
{

    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id","name","number","skypeId","address" },
            null, null, null, null, "name asc"); 

    int x=0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String[] b1=new String[]{cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4)};

            list.add(b1);

            x=x+1;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    } 
    cursor.close();

    return list;
}
```

and to show it in a list view :

```
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<String[]> names2 =null ;
     names2 = dm.selectAll();

    stg1=new String[names2.size()]; 

    int x=0;
    String stg;

    for (String[] name : names2) {
        stg = name[1]+" - "+name[2]+ " - "+name[3]+" - "+name[4];

        stg1[x]=stg;
        x++;
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(   
            this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   
            stg1);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

refer this tutorial you will get an idea: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create an Database class instance in your Activity or ListActivity to access `getAllCart` as

```
public class TempActivity extends Activity {
DatabaseHandler db;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(TempActivity.this);

        // Reading all Carts
        List<Cart> Carts = db.getAllCart(); //<< get all Cart details here    
       //... your code here..
```

and for showing Carts ArrayList values in ListView you will need to create an Custom Adapter for Adding all items in ListView rows .

for Create ListView with Custom Adapter you can view these tutorials :

[Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

[Android ListView example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Comment: So i use the "Carts" to populate the listview?

Comment: @user1850666 : yes you will need to pass Carts ArrayList to custom Adapter constructor