# How to display datas from a Database in `ListView` in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I created an App to get value from user via `EditText` and store it in `Database`. I have no problem with that. Now i have to display the datas of Database in a `ListView`. Here i used an `AlertDialog` to display them.
My Code is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mute_List", MODE_APPEND, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists user(Number INTEGER);");
    Button add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mute_List", MODE_APPEND, null);
            db.execSQL("create table if not exists user(Number INTEGER);");
            String cno=num.getText().toString();
            if(cno.length()==0){
                show("Error", "Field Cannot be Empty");
            }else{
            db.execSQL("insert into user values('"+cno+"');");
            show("Success", "Added Successfully");
            }
        }
    });

    Button show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("Mute_List", MODE_APPEND, null);
            db.execSQL("create table if not exists user(Number INTEGER);");
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select*from user",null);
            if (c.getCount()==0) 
            {
                show("Error","No Records Found" );
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Records Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                buffer.append(c.getString(0)+"\n");
            }
            show("User Details", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void show(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: you can look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534465/sqlite-to-listviewandroidhives-version#

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select*from user",null);
```

to

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from user",null);
```

also dont execute db create table command in activity.